# Chart Y-Axis fixed interval

Tags: highcharts

I want my chart to have a "fixed zoom" on y-axis on certain interval. I don't know if that's a right way to describe it, but I'll give you an example.

This is how my chart looks like right now:

[image]

While I'm fine with my x-axis (hours) generating automatically, I want my y-axis not based on series (now it's 8k, 10k. 12k etc - so thats 2k interval), but on fixed value, for example 5k (5k, 10k, ... up to 50k)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! It's [yAxis.tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval).

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart
    yAxis:
        tickInterval: 5000
```

Coffeescript Above.